# Linq2DB Nlog or logging

Tags: sql, nlog, miniprofiler, linq2db

is there a way to log all linq2DB sql queries that are made to he database with NLog?

I cannot find any realistic example. There is something for miniprofiler, but this doesn't help me, because I have not experience with it.

[pull request](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/issues/63)

[example](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9460950)

[example 2](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/MiniProfiler/MiniProfiler.IDbProfiler.cs)

Comment: maybe this is helpful? http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=647

Comment: or what about this: https://github.com/usarskyy/VXCore.MiniProfiler

Comment: I ended up asking directly in github.com. https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/issues/646

Answer (score 21):

Inside your Setup method you could turn on Trace and setup WriteTraceLine to Console.WriteLine

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    LinqToDB.Data.DataConnection.TurnTraceSwitchOn();
    LinqToDB.Data.DataConnection.WriteTraceLine = (message, displayName) => { Console.WriteLine($"{message} {displayName}"); };
}
```

This will write all executed SQL Queries (together with params) to the Console